# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'subscribeToTopic' (at Appointment.vue:28:10)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs3

I am trying to import a function located in a separate javascript file into the Vue project that I am working on. I am sure that the route of the file is correct but I keep on receiving an error like this.
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/C:/Users/david/OneDrive/바탕 화면/Gothenburg University/Mini Project (Distributed Systems)/group3/MQTT-Connector/listSlots.js' does not provide an export named 'subscribeToTopic' (at Appointment.vue:28:10)

I am importing the file like this

```
import { subscribeToTopic } from '../../../MQTT-Connector/listSlots'
```

And the function is exported like this

```
export function subscribeToTopic() {
    try {
        mqttSubscriber.subscribeToTopic('slot-details');
        console.log("Slot details saved as a json file.")
    } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving slot details:', error.message);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!

I tried everything like trying to use const instead of import statement or try using export default. However, I had no luck

Comment: what if you do `import { subscribeToTopic } from '../../../MQTT-Connector/listSlots.js'` - I realise you have some build system or something that's probably adding the `.js` for you (since the error message has the `.js` in it) but humour me :p

Comment: or, `import * as X from '../../../MQTT-Connector/listSlots'; console.log(X);` to see what's exported?